# Excel create a button that puts a value in a specific cell

Tags: excel, button, vba

I'm trying to create an excel spreadsheet that, whenever I press a button, it reads information from one sheet and (according to that information) fills in a cell on a different sheet with a certain value.

For example:

A student enters in their test answers.  The excel document checks all the answers against a database and calculates scores and associates them with certain objectives (I've already got that taken care of).

Then, the student presses an "update" button.  The program would read the student's name (which provides the row #) and the test they took (which provides the column--I'm still not sure how to come up with the specific column with letters, so that wouldd be helpful too) and it updates that cell with the student's score.

How would I do that?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? do you have a particular problem with a particular code?

Comment: This is a pretty daunting task for a new programmer, and a question that's unfortunately too vague, and hence unlikely to get much of a response here... http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, kind of the code like you said, i ever do it before. This i can answer for you. But cause i dont see your effort at all. So i just give you my code and explain it, then you need to change it to be your question code. Ok?

```
      c = TB1.Value >> (My textbox for user to fill in their name that same with the sheet row value)

    Cells.Find(What:=c, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        myRow = ActiveCell.Row
        rtb = myRow >> My Row XX Value just like you said want to know at what row hold that value.

    e = coltb.Text >> (My textbox for user to fill in their date value that will be find in column)
    Cells.Find(What:=e, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
        myColumn = ActiveCell.Column
        ctb = myColumn >>> (My Column XX value just like for know what is the column that hold the value)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rtb, ctb) = Val(Score) > Your RTB(Row value) + CTB(Column Value) then the score of your test.
```

May be like this, isn't it you want?
This code is used in VBA, cause your tag using VBA

Hope will be helpful